# Can't POST to /v2/entities

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

We can successfully receive our X-Auth Token by making a call to https://orion.lab.fiware.org/token but, following the official documentation, we are getting error responses from the global Orion instance

Here is a sample **call** we are using from the documentation:

```
curl localhost:1026/v2/entities -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @- <<EOF
{
  "id": "Room1",
  "type": "Room",
  "temperature": {
    "value": 23,
    "type": "Float"
  },
  "pressure": {
    "value": 720,
    "type": "Integer"
  }
}
EOF
```

**Response:**

```
Cannot POST /v2/entities
```

Answer (score 1):

Note your curl command doesn't include the X-Auth-Token header. You should add `--header 'X-Auth-Token: ...'` in order to include it. Please have a detailed look to [the quick start guide](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/develop/quick_start_guide/index.html).

**EDIT:** in addition, use port 1026 (as shown in quick start guide). Not sure, but probably you also need to use http schema (not https). In the comment below this answer I see you are using `https://orion.lab.fiware.org/v2/entities` but it should be `http://orion.lab.fiware.org:1026/v2/entities`.

Comment: The request on my question was directly copied from the official documentation as a sample, of course I am including the token in my original request. Please find it below. The response is the same. `curl https://orion.lab.fiware.org/v2/entities -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'X-Auth-Token: <my_token>' -d @- <<EOF
{
  "id": "Room1",
  "type": "Room",
  "temperature": {
    "value": 23,
    "type": "Float"
  },
  "pressure": {
    "value": 720,
    "type": "Integer"
  }
}
EOF`

Comment: Answer has been edited to add aditional information based on your comment.

Comment: I tried http with port 1026, this time I get a command prompt and no response. Can you get a response with this request?

Comment: I have just tested and works perfectly. See session log at https://gist.github.com/fgalan/f3c8e0ac3489741c69c5ef897de4ecd3